# How to express "I'm so X that Y?"

Tags: syntax, particle-くらい

I found these two grammar points but I can't seem to be able to use them to express what I want.

> くらい、ほど

Let's say I want to say "I'm so full that I will never walk again"
The closest I can think of is this

> 歩くことはないくらいお腹いっぱい

But is there a way to express the same idea but reverse the order?
I believe this one would mean something else

> お腹いっぱいほど歩くことはない

Answer (score 5, accepted):

英文の文法に忠実に訳すなら

「歩こうとは思わないくらいお腹がいっぱいだ。」か
「お腹いっぱいすぎるので歩かないだろう。」

となると思いますが、日本人はこの場合

「歩けないくらいお腹いっぱいだ」
「お腹いっぱいすぎて歩けない」
　(←naturally speaking)

以上のように「お腹いっぱい」という原因に、「歩けない」という、行為の不可能を結果として結びつけて喋ることが多いので、単純に打ち消しの意思の文で表現することは少ないと思います。